# Score doesn't start with 0 at the beginning of the game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game and I try to pass data from scene to scene ( the score). The problem is when I start again the game in unity the score remain 4-5 , 10 depends on the last session and don't start normal with 0 from the first scene . (I still want the data do be saved from scene to scene but the score to reset when I click run in unity)
I have 2 scripts , what should I change?

**Score**

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public int score;
    public Button button;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
        GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        Debug.LogFormat("Current Score: {0}", score);
        Button btn = GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);
    }

    public void AddScore(int s)
    {
        score += s;
    }

    public int GetScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        score++;
    }
}
```

**ScorePanelUpdater**

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScorePanelUpdater : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("Score");
        if(go == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed");
            this.enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        Score gs = go.GetComponent<Score>();

        GetComponent<Text>().text = " Score: " + gs.GetScore();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you could do is save your score as a **static variable**. That way you can access it from every scene but the value will be reset once you restart the game.

```c#
public static int score = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `DontDestroyOnLoad` so your instance and the according values anyway are also maintained in every scene. **You don't need to / should not use `PlayerPrefs` at all.**

---

To answer your question: you have

```c#
void OnDestroy()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);
}
```

so the last value is always stored once this instance is destroyed .. when does this happen? Since you are using `DontDestroyOnLoad` it happens **never** except when you close the game, exit play mode => the last value is stored and recovered on the next game start due to

```c#
void Start()
{
    score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
    ...
}
```

**Solution**: either reset it to `0` in `OnDestroy` (`PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", 0);`) or **better remove `PlayerPrefs` completely from your script! You don't need it.**

---

The more simple way is already mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57608996/7111561): you could simply go with a `static` field. Again since you are using `DontDestroyOnLoad` this actually wouldn't be necessary since it stays available through all scenes anyway.

However there are some other issues in your code:

Don't repeatedly use `Find` and `GetComponent` and even worse if done in `Update` .. these are very inefficient! Also you shouldn't use `Update` at all for things that do only have to change event driven once the value of `score` is actually changed.

Since you have a lot of other issues with efficiency I would extend this a bit and wouldn't use it inside of a `MonoBehaviour` but completely apart in a `static class` like e.g.

```c#
public static class GameInformation
{
    private static int _score = 0;

    // have an event to register listeners
    public static event Action<int> OnScoreChanged;

    // public property
    public static int Score
    {
        get { return _score;}
        set 
        {
            _score = value;

            // invoke an event to inform all registered listeners
            OnScoreChanged?.Invoke(_score);
        }
    }
}
```

this class doesn't need an instance but can be accessed from everywhere during runtime.

Now in `Score` you can do

```c#
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public Button button;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        if(!button) button = GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => { GameInformation.Score++; });

        GameInformation.OnScoreChanged -= OnScoreChanged;
        GameInformation.OnScoreChanged += OnScoreChanged;

        // invoke once now with current value
        Debug.LogFormat("Current Score: {0}", GameInformation.Score);
        OnScoreChanged(GameInformation.Score);

    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        GameInformation.OnScoreChanged -= OnScoreChanged;
    }

    private void OnScoreChanged(int newValue)
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + newValue;
    }


    // These two make not much sense .. since the value already was public
    // you wouldn't need methods for this
    // anyway now you could directly do it on GameInformation instead
    public void AddScore(int s)
    {
        GameInformation.Score += s;
    }

    public int GetScore()
    {
        return GameInformation.Score;
    }
}
```

and in `ScorePanelUpdater` also simply add callbacks

```c#
public class ScorePanelUpdater : MonoBehaviour
{
    // better if you can already reference this via Inspector
    [SerializeField] Text text;

    void Awake()
    {
        if(!text) text = GetComponent<Text>();

        // it's always save to remove listeners before adding them
        // makes sure it is added only once
        GameInformation.OnScoreChanged -= OnScoreChanged;
        GameInformation.OnScoreChanged += OnScoreChanged;

        // invoke once now with current value
        OnScoreChanged(GameInformation.Score);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        GameInformation.OnScoreChanged -= OnScoreChanged;
    }

    private void OnScoreChanged(int newValue)
    {
        text.text = "Score: " + newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: game information script gives me error at Action<int>

Comment: what error? it shouldn't ;) you might need `using System;`

Comment: And error at text.text = text = "Score: " + newValue; in the Panel Script

Comment: yeah that was a typo .. `text.text = "Score: " + newValue;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following to the `Start()` (first scene)  or `OnApplicationQuit()` (last scene):

```c#
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", 0);
```

In case of `Start()`:

```c#
void Start()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", 0); // THIS LINE

    //TODO: OPTIMIZE THE FOLLOWING CODE
    score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);
    GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    Debug.LogFormat("Current Score: {0}", score);
    Button btn = GetComponent<Button>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
}
```

Comment: this `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", 0); score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);` doesn't make much sense ... then you can simply say `score = 0;` and not use `PlayerPrefs` at all

Comment: @derHugo, of course, my friend, of course... I just help people to solve the problems from their point of view. If someone writes that he/she have some troubles with PlayerPrefs, I just tell him the vector how's that troubles may be solved. The vector, but not completely solution. I let people to think by themself, to find a better solution when they will start to think like "Yep, PlayerPrefs is not a better way to do it in that case". If we gave to people ready-to-use solutions, they actually will stop looking for something else in the case of one problem.

Comment: @derHugo, And if they'll stop to looking for additional info... Yes, they'll solve the problem more accurate using the ready-to-use near-perfect solution we publishing here. But in the "global" case they'll get less, and less, and less of skills, beacause when peoples looking for one thing, they'll get more peripheral info about another. Thank you.

Comment: I understand your point .. the issue however in this case is the OP using a wrong tool in the first place .. it is a workaround what you provide here and valid ofcourse .. however I would rather tackle the actual issue which is using `PlayerPrefs` where there is no need/sense to do so ;)